# Вывод информации о двухмёрном массиве

Tags: c, массивы

Всем привет. При написании программы у меня возникла проблема с записью данных в двумерный массив. Программа должна запросить у пользователя ввод данных из клавиатуры и затем выводить на экран такую информацию:

1. Информация, которая была введена пользователем
2. Вычислять среднее для каждого набора из пяти значений
3. Найти макс элемент
4. Выводить результаты на экран

Моя проблема заключается в том, что при выводе данных на экран у меня выводит другие значения (то-есть я думаю что информация не была записана в массив), Подскажите, пожалуйста, что надо исправить?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 5
 void inizialization(int arr[][COLS]);
 void average(int arr_2[][COLS]);
 void the_max(int arr_3[][COLS]);
int main (void)
{
    int i, j;
    int array[ROWS][COLS];/* = {
        {1,2,3,4,5},
        {1,2,3,4,5},
        {1,2,3,4,5},
    }; */
    inizialization(array);
    average(array);
    the_max(array);
    putchar('\n');  
    return 0;
}
    void inizialization(int arr[][COLS])
    {
        printf("Input numbers: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            {
                while((scanf("%d", &arr[i][j])) == 1)
                    printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
     void average(int arr_2[][COLS])
     {
        int sum = 0, i;
        for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
                sum += arr_2[i][j];
            printf("The sum of %d is %d\r\n", i, sum / 2);
        }

     }
      void the_max(int arr_3[][COLS])
      {
        int max = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            {
                if(max < arr_3[i][j])
                    max = arr_3[i][j];
            }
        }
        printf("The max value is %d\r\n", max);

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции inizialization: while((scanf("%d", &arr[i][j])) **!**= 1). Но лучше так:

```
void inizialization(int arr[][COLS]){

printf("Input numbers:\n");
for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
        do{
            printf("%d, %d ->", i, j);}while(scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]) == EOF);}}}
```

Comment: спасибо вам за вариант, сейчас поробуем ево на програме)

Answer (score 1):

```
while((scanf("%d", &arr[i][j])) == 1)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
```

Что происходит здесь? Пока успешно считывается значение в `arr[i][j]` (результат `scanf` равен 1), оно выводится и считывается туда же новое значение...

У вас вообще-то тут бесконечный цикл, который просто не даст делать ничего, кроме вечного считывания (ну, его можно прервать... но вопрос не в этом). Откровенно говоря, мне просто непонятно, как вы вообще переходите к какой-то другой части кода?...